# How can I generate a vector of vectors in a nice way?

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I would like to have a function that has this definition:

```
vector<vector<int>> create_lists(int no_lists, int no_per_list)
```

The first argument is the number of sublist and the second argument is the number of items per sublist. Each list shall contain a subrange of a sequence of ints, so a call

```
create_lists(10,10);
```

will create 10 sublists, the first ranging from 0 to 9, second from 10 to 19 and so on.

I have done several versions of it, but they all feels clumsy. Is there a nice and elegant way to do this?

Comment: Show us your best version. If you can verbalize why you think it's clumsy, that's a bonus.

Comment: As @huu mentions, you should post your code, but probably the most important would be to migrate the question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ where your code will be imporved.

Comment: @Aleksandar I'm not sure code review is the best place for a code fragment, since they like complete projects over there.

Comment: @jaggedSpire This would be considered a snippet and closed. The full code would be welcome at Code Review. Fix first, migrate later.

Comment: A vector of vector is a clumsy data structure if all internal vectors have the same size: Use a single vector and calculate individual ranges, instead.

Answer (score 8):

I rarely see an opportunity to say "use [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)", so I'm not going to miss this one!

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> create_lists(int no_lists, int no_per_list)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(no_lists,
                                    std::vector<int>(no_per_list));

    for (int i = 0; i < no_lists; ++i) {
        std::iota(v[i].begin(), v[i].end(), no_per_list * i);
    } 

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create the 2d vector with its default values as

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> temp(no_lists, std::vector<int>(no_per_list));
```

Then I would iterate through each vector and [`transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) them into the sequence values using

```
for (auto & e : temp)
    std::transform(e.begin(), e.end(), e.begin(), [](int foo){static int counter = 0; return counter++;});
```

Putting it all together the function would be:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> create_lists(int no_lists, int no_per_list)
{
    int counter = 0;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> temp(no_lists, std::vector<int>(no_per_list));
    for (auto & e : temp)
        std::generate(e.begin(), e.end(), [&counter](){return counter++;});
    return temp;
}
```

And you can see it running in this <kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29959eef0242d936)</kbd>

Comment: There is no need to use `std::transform` here you are not transforming a range but creating a sequence

Comment: And the `static` make the code works only once: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1a9cfe726a59f4e).

Comment: @AaryamanSagar Thanks for the suggestion.  Since Barry is already using `iota` I switched it to `generate`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the least exciting answer of them all, but I would probably simply use two for loops.  This way seems least obscure and quickest to understand to me, which means the code is easier to understand later

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> create_lists(int no_lists, int no_per_list)
{
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> lol(no_lists, std::vector<int>(no_per_list));
  int count = 0;
  for(auto &list : lol)
    for(auto &v : list)
    {
      v = count;
      ++count;
    }
  return lol;
}
```

This does one allocation and deallocation more than strictly necessary (the temporary `vector<int>` passed to the `vector<vector<int>>` constructor), but trying to avoid that would make the code slightly more complex and would probably not make much of a difference (your doing `no_lists+1` allocations anyway).